# Equivalent of Rust include_str! in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Does Haskell have something like Rust's `include_str!` macro? My use case is seeding data into a Postgres database for consumption in a `yesod` web app. The way I'm thinking of loading it in is more or less taken from the [Yesod Cookbook example](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod-cookbook/blob/master/cookbook/Adding-Seed-Data-to-Scaffolded-Site.md). But instead of defining the seed data in a haskell file, I would like to store it in a JSON file, and include it in the binary artifact that gets built.

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/file-embed-0.0.12.0/docs/Data-FileEmbed.html (never used it myself)

Answer (score 1):

You have several options for that. I can recommend file-embed, since I have used it with success. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/file-embed-0.0.12.0/docs/Data-FileEmbed.html

Like other solutions, file-embed relies on Template Haskell. I guess this is not an issue for you, since you are using Yesod.

```
-- Look at the type. This is not IO ByteString, but plain ByteString
seedRaw :: Data.ByteString.ByteString
seedRaw = $(embedFile "seed-dir/seed.json")

-- Here you get your seed
seed :: Seed
seed = parseSeed seedRaw
```